# Missing data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, syntax

I need to find the data that is present in Oracle, but missing from SQL Server.

I have tried the below query, but am getting the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "PS.TXN_ID" could not be bound.

```
SELECT TXN_ID 
FROM OPENQUERY(PEX,'SELECT TXN_ID FROM PEX.PEX_SALE_TRAN_CUBE ')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TXN_ID 
                  FROM  PA_TRANSACTIONS PT
                  WHERE PT.TXN_ID = PS.TXN_ID)
```

Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 1):

You have not aliased the OPENQUERY result set as "PS" in your supplied query. Without the alias "PS", SQL Server does not know to what this refers, so PS.TXN_ID is meaningless.

Try this:

```
SELECT TXN_ID 
FROM OPENQUERY(PEX,'SELECT TXN_ID FROM PEX.PEX_SALE_TRAN_CUBE ') ps
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select TXN_ID from PA_TRANSACTIONS PT WHERE PT.TXN_ID =PS.TXN_ID)
```

Alternatively, try using the EXCEPT operator:

```
SELECT TXN_ID 
FROM OPENQUERY(PEX,'SELECT TXN_ID FROM PEX.PEX_SALE_TRAN_CUBE ') 
EXCEPT 
SELECT TXN_ID FROM PA_TRANSACTIONS
```

[EXCEPT Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You can add that there is a slight difference between the two solutions. If the openquery subquery returns some duplicate `TXN_ID` values, the 1st solution will show them all. The 2nd will apply `distinct` and remove the duplicates.